# Make menu bar view not hide when clicking outside view

Tags: objective-c, macos, statusbar, menubar, nspopover

I'll attach a picture right off the bat so we're all on the same page.  Here is my application...

[image]

I am attempting to make the NSPopover clickable, but no matter what behavior it is set to the application still hides because the click is outside of the menu view bounds.

```
   [myPopover setBehavior:NSPopoverBehaviorApplicationDefined]
```

I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on how to either make the menu view stay open even when clicked outside of its bounds or make the popover clickable another way.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems like you might have to consider using UIPresentationControlller. Please go througuh the documentation, and you might find good solution for this.

Comment: UIPresentationControlller is for iOS. -- Have you filed a radar? I can't think of a way around this.

Comment: @Taylor I had noticed that Fantastical has a similar functionality through use of an "anchor" button in the menu view.  I messaged the devs and found out that they merely use an NSWindow from the start and circumvent and status bar defaults.  I suppose this is an okay solution...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching around it seems the best solution to this is to create an NSWindow subclass and merely pin it at the desired location.